# Increasing intervals in an array, check

Tags: c, arrays

So I'm trying to check if an array that was previously inputted is increasing in intervals of 1, starting with the number 1 and ending with n (n being the array size).

Here's what I got so far:

```
    for (int i =0; i<n;i++){
                for (next=i;next<n;next++){
                    if(arr[i]+1 = arr[next]){
                        x = 1;  //ignore this, it relates to the rest of the code.
                    }
                    else{
                        printf ("\nThis is not a permutation.");
                        break;
                }
        }
}
```

Now, my thinking is that this code would compare parameters that are next to each other, and if the following parameter is equal to the previous +1, then it is obviously increasing by 1. Problem is, when this is false, it wont print "This is not a permutation," and wont break the loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Also, any insight as to checking if the array starts with the number 1 would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "Also, any insight as to checking if the array starts with the number 1 would be appreciated." And why can't you just check if `arr[0] == 1`?

Comment: You will get more hits if you tag your post with the programming language.

Comment: Are you asking how to test if your array contains the values `[1,2,3,...,n]`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in this line:

```
if(arr[i]+1 = arr[next]){
```

You intended comparison:

```
if(arr[i]+1 == arr[next]){
```

Comment: `=` vs `==` strikes again!

Comment: Ok, thanks, I changed that. Now, it is always printing "This is not a permutation," non stop even if it is correct. It seems it is defaulting to the else no matter what.

Comment: Can you clean up your code a bit first? I see a missing brace, and it might be easier to spot if everything is neatly formatted.

Comment: Are you sure you have sequential values in your `arr`. Why don't you print elements before comparing them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `if(arr[i]+1 == arr[next])` instead of `if(arr[i]+1 = arr[next])`??

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check that a sequence is increasing, why are you comparing every element against the others? You should only need one for loop:

```
for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    if (arr[i - 1] + 1 == arr[i])
        ... // keep going
    else
        ... // not a permutation
}
```

Basically, what your code does is check that *every* element after the i-th one is greater than that i-th one by one. Ultimately, this leads to an impossible case (as two numbers must be equal but must differ by one at the same time).

Comment: Well, I tried that, and it seems to be comparing them, but even if it is increasing by 1, it defaults to the else clause.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to test if `arr[0] == 1` and every subsequent array element is `1` greater than the previous element. Isn't that the same as checking your array for the values `[1,2,3,...,n]`?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++n) {
    if (arr[i] != i + 1) {
        printf("\nThis is not a permutation.");
        break;
    }
}
```